# Symfony 3 Login as Startpage

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-3.1

Simple ToDO:

i want that when i go www.mysmyfonyproject.com, 
that , when user is not logged in, than the login-page
should shown.
Otherwise the user-landingpage should shown.

i try to make a bad solution in my home controller like this:

```
/**
* @Route("/")
*/
public function indexAction()
{
    if ( 
        ! $this->get('security.authorization_checker')
        ->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
    ) 
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    } else {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('user-landingpage');
    }
}
```

but here is a ERROR : unknown path /login.

Comment: You redirect a User to the /login page when not logged in instead of using a response to show the login page. Make sure the login page is defined in your application.

Comment: I Try to make a "return $this->render" with the path where the login template is : default/login.html.twig. But than i got the error that this path is unknown. wenn i call the url www.myproject.de/login than the login page will shown correctly.

here my routing:

Name | Path

acme_user_default_index |

user_landingpage | /user-landingpage

users | /users

fos_user_security_login | /login

fos_user_security_check | /login_check

fos_user_security_logout | /logout

I use FOSUserBundle and create aAcmeUserBundle to overwrite the FoSUser.